# React.js: Is it possible to namespace child components while still using JSX to refer to them?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So let's say I have a component called `ImageGrid` and it is defined as below:

```
window.ImageGrid = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="image-grid">
                <ImageGridItem />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

As you can see it includes a child react component called `ImageGridItem`.  Which is defined below.

```
window.ImageGridItem = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="item-container">something</div>
        );
    }
});
```

This works fine as long as both are directly properties of `window`.  But this is kind of horrible so I'd like to group up all my react components under a namespace of `window.myComponents` for example.

So the definitions change to:

```
window.myComponents.ImageGrid     = React.createClass({...});
window.myComponents.ImageGridItem = React.createClass({...});
```

The problem now is that as `ImageGrid` refers to `<ImageGridItem />` in it's render() function, the JS version of this gets compiled out to JS as `ImageGridItem()` which of course is undefined since it's now actually `myComponents.ImageGridItem()` and react complains it can't find it.

Yes I realise I can just not write JSX for that component include and manually do `myComponents.ImageGridItem({attr: 'val'})` but I'd really prefer to use the JSX html syntax shortcut as it's much easier to read and develop with.

Are there any ways to get this to work while still using the `<ImageGridItem />` syntax for children?  And if not is it possible to define the JS namespace within the JSX?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This pull request was just merged:

https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/760

It allows you to write things like `<myComponents.ImageGridItem />` in React 0.11 and newer.

That said, a proper module system is the recommended way to manage dependencies to avoid pulling in code that you don't need.

Comment: But even if you use a module system, what if you have multiple react classes being returned from one module? How would you reference each individual class in this case? I posted a related question here about this exact issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23739166/26510

Comment: The simplest way is to split each class into a separate module.

Comment: The pull request has been merged, so if you get the latest from the master repo, you'll be good!

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there isn't a way to do this.  Namespacing with JSX is on the todo list.

Most people use some kind of module system (browserify, webpack, requirejs), which replace namespacing and allow components to be used easily.  There are a lot of other benefits, so I very much recommend looking into it.