# ReactJS and RequireJS -> How to use multiple classes returned from one module?

Tags: javascript, scope, requirejs, reactjs

I've got a RequireJS module that returns multiple ReactJS classes that I'd like to be immediately available to the JSX scope.

e.g.

```
define(["require"], function (require) {

  var SimpleClass = React.createClass({displayName: 'SimpleClass',
    render: function() {
      return <div>HELLO DUDE {this.props.name}</div>;
    }
  });
  var AnotherSimpleClass = React.createClass({displayName: 'AnotherSimpleClass',
    render: function() {
      return <div>SUPER DUDE {this.props.name}</div>;
    }
  });


  var result = 
  {
    AnotherSimpleClass: AnotherSimpleClass,
    SimpleClass: SimpleClass
  };

  return result;
});
```

I'd like to be able to use these in React/JSX like so (pseudocode):

```
define(["require","jsx!app/my_classes"], function (require, MyClasses) {

  React.renderComponent(
    <div>
      <MyClasses.SimpleClass name="Test" />
      <MyClasses.AnotherSimpleClass name="John" />
    </div>
  , this.el);

});
```

when I do, React fails to find my module classes. It only works if I expose the classes to the scope, ie:

```
define(["require","jsx!app/my_classes"], function (require, MyClasses) {

  var SimpleClass = MyClasses.SimpleClass;
  var AnotherSimpleClass = MyClasses.AnotherSimpleClass;

  React.renderComponent(
    <div>
      <SimpleClass name="Test" />
      <AnotherSimpleClass name="John" />
    </div>
  , this.el);

});
```

How can I do this? I know I can extract them to the current scope one by one, or extract them to the global scope, but it seems I should be able to use them from JSX without modification. Thanks!

Note that I know I could just expose them to the global scope with a function like so:

```
  function exposeClasses(obj){
    for (var prop in obj)
    {
      window[prop] = obj[prop];
    }
  }

  exposeClasses(MyClasses);
```

but I'd prefer to leave them in their namespaces if possible. Note that this is [similar to this question being asked here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653616/react-js-is-it-possible-to-namespace-child-components-while-still-using-jsx-to)

Comment: Looking at the question you referenced, it looks like [this PR](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/760) will need to land before this will work.

Comment: good stuff! this was just committed so it's now legit... thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now supported in ReactJS, as [this pull request](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/760) to add this feature has been merged.

Comment: For other people wondering which official release this landed in, it was 0.11.0